# Get Selected Item ListBox WP8.1 C#

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-phone-8.1

I try to get the item to export to pdf
When I am holding the item, it shows me a menuFlyout **Export to PDF**

 so I try to get the index to be able to export it.

Xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="WritePad_CSharpSample.ReadWritePadNoteList"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:WritePad_CSharpSample"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="Read All Notes with listbox" Margin="9,-7,0,0" FontSize="28"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <ListBox Background="Transparent" Margin="6" Height="auto" BorderThickness="2" MaxHeight="580" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="listBoxobj" SelectionChanged="listBoxobj_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="350" >
                    <Border Margin="5" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Grid Holding="Grid_Holding" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                                <MenuFlyout>
                                    <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="EditButton"
                                            Text="Export To PDF"
                                            Click="EditButton_Click"
                                                    />
                                </MenuFlyout>
                            </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="NameTxt" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="28" Foreground="White"/>
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,35,0" Grid.Row="3" x:Name="CreateddateTxt" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding CreationDate}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

</Grid>

<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Label="New" Click="AddNewNoteClick" />
            <AppBarButton x:Name="deleteAppBarButton" Label="Delete All" Click="DeleteAllNoteClick" />
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

C#

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Text;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.System;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using WritePad_CSharpSample.Helpers;
using WritePad_CSharpSample.Model;

namespace WritePad_CSharpSample
{

    public sealed partial class ReadWritePadNoteList : Page
    {
        ObservableCollection<WritePadFileContent> DB_ContactList = new ObservableCollection<WritePadFileContent>();

        int Selected_ContactId = 0;
        DatabaseHelperClass Db_Helper = new DatabaseHelperClass();
        WritePadFileContent currentcontact = new WritePadFileContent();
        string name = "";
        string desc = "";
        public ReadWritePadNoteList()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += ReadWritePadFileContentList_Loaded;
        }

        private void ReadWritePadFileContentList_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ReadAllWritePadFileContent dbnote = new ReadAllWritePadFileContent();
            DB_ContactList = dbnote.GetAllContacts();//Get all DB contacts 
            if (DB_ContactList.Count > 0)
                deleteAppBarButton.IsEnabled = true;
            else
                deleteAppBarButton.IsEnabled = false;
            listBoxobj.ItemsSource = DB_ContactList.OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).ToList();//Binding DB data to LISTBOX and Latest contact ID can Display first. 

        }




    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
            { }
private void AddNewNoteClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


    Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    }

private void listBoxobj_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int SelectedContactID = 0;
    if (listBoxobj.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        WritePadFileContent listitem = listBoxobj.SelectedItem as WritePadFileContent;//Get slected listbox item contact ID 
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(DeleteUpdateNote), SelectedContactID = listitem.Id);

    }
}

private async void DeleteAllNoteClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        var dialog = new MessageDialog("Are you sure you want to remove all your data ?");
        dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("No", new UICommandInvokedHandler(Command)));
        dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Yes", new UICommandInvokedHandler(Command)));
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }

    private void Command(IUICommand command)
    {
        if (command.Label.Equals("Yes"))
        {
            DatabaseHelperClass Db_Helper = new DatabaseHelperClass();
            Db_Helper.DeleteAllWritePadFileContent();//delete all DB contacts 
            DB_ContactList.Clear();//Clear collections 
            //Btn_Delete.IsEnabled = false;
            deleteAppBarButton.IsEnabled = false;
            listBoxobj.ItemsSource = DB_ContactList;
        }
    }





    private void Grid_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FrameworkElement senderElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
            FlyoutBase flyoutBase = FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout(senderElement);

            flyoutBase.ShowAt(senderElement);
        }

        private async void EditButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            WritePadFileContent listitem = (sender as ListBox).DataContext as WritePadFileContent;
            MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog(listitem.Name.ToString());
            await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
            //pdf code work
        }
    }
}
```

The Exception here, it return null, so any help to get the item when I am holding from the listbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you tap and hold, the ListViewItem doesn't get selected, so SelectedItem will always be null. Instead, you should get the value of the DataContext from the MenuFlyoutItem, like this:

```
private async void EditButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WritePadFileContent listitem = (e.OriginalSource as MenuFlyoutItem).DataContext as WritePadFileContent;
        MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog(listitem.Name.ToString());
        await messageDialog.ShowAsync();



        //code for export to pdf, it works
    }
```

Comment: the list  name is listBoxobj

Comment: how do you add items to it?

Comment: I have this method to add item
private void listBoxobj_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int SelectedContactID = 0;
            if (listBoxobj.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                WritePadFileContent listitem = listBoxobj.SelectedItem as WritePadFileContent;//Get slected listbox item contact ID 
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(DeleteUpdateNote), SelectedContactID = listitem.Id);

            }
        }
and even if I try ur method, never enter that part

Comment: @Amin where you got error on **EditButton_Click or listBoxobj_SelectionChanged ??**

Comment: on EditButton_Click, but not an error but never enter the part to get the slected item, it gone directly to export to pdf code

Comment: That means that listBoxobj.SelectedIndex is -1, so you don't have an item selected. Probably the item doesn't get selected when you hold it and tap on the menu option. There are many ways to do this, but probably the easiest one would be to handle the PointerPressed event and get the item from the DataContext.

Comment: So I need a button?? just want to get selected item from listbox then export it, I tyied this to show the selected item but nothing, the app crash: WritePadFileContent listitem = (sender as ListBox).DataContext as WritePadFileContent;
            MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog(listitem.Name.ToString());
            await messageDialog.ShowAsync();

Comment: No, you don't need a button. Can you give us a link to the source of the project? Or at least the full xaml and the xaml.cs files for this page, so we can take a better look at what is happening.

Comment: it works for me, can you tell me on which line do you get the exception? and what is the exception type and message?

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: on which line do you get this exception?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82505/discussion-between-thewindev-and-amin).

Comment: When I try to sho the listitem.name